# Build Android Module on 4.0

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx

I just created a new Module inside a Project in IntelliJ. Now I want to deploy/launch the App on my mobile device.

The error I get after the build is the following one

```
Android Dex: [Android] the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Android Dex: [Android] If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Android Dex: [Android] building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Android Dex: [Android] will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Android Dex: [Android] prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
```

[Image](https://twitter.com/faebeee/status/396423947324907520/photo/1/large)

Comment: Do you have any classes which are declared in one of the "standard" packages? (java.*, android.*)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in a Open source Game I studied once. You are linking the android.jar of the platform you are building for directly (to be able to use Android code in the core project probably, as the makers of that game).

This is a very bad Design choice, which will lead to pain and suffering :p If you want to use Android specific code, give a check to this wiki entry: [Interfacing with Platform Specific code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code)